# webpack-dev-server does not create initial bundle on start

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have built a basic babel webpack starter project that i clone from git. The git repository has no dest/output/build folder nor does it have any initial build files. I am knew to webpack so i assumed that when the `webpack-dev-server` started up it would create a folder (in my case 'build') and do a first time compilation of the source files. Instead i am forced to start the process manually only then after the initial compilation will `webpack-dev-server` compile the changes.

What am i missing ?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "babel-webpack-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Babel Webpack Stater Pack for compiling ES2015/ES6, ES2016/ES7 and ES2017 code doen to ES5. This will allow for the use of ES6 modules and later ECMAScript features such as async/await. Also includes a webpack-dev-server to auto load server without having to re-compile.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode=development",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --output-public-path=/build/ --mode=development"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.16.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
 // Load Node modules
const path = require('path');

// Export modules
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/app.js'        
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: '/node_modules',
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['env']
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`webpack-dev-server` will not put your `app.bundle.js` in your working directory, it will compile your files in-memory.

If you want to access the files, add public path to the output option or which you have done there in the `npm start` script.

```
output: {
    ...
    publicPath: '/build/'
}
```

Now, your files will be available in `localhost:<port>/build/app.bundle.js`

You can check [this site](https://survivejs.com/webpack/developing/webpack-dev-server/#webpack-watch-mode-and-webpack-dev-server-) out for more information

Comment: If i understand your correctly the webpack-dev-server serves up the changes from memory but does not write/create the files/folder? The fact that assumed or thought it did was imply the fact that i had already created the files/folder?

Comment: The anser to the first question is 'Yes'. But I don't understand the second question. please clarify a bit. Added a reference in the answer

Comment: What i did when i realised that the webpack-dev-server did not create a new build file was to run the build comand first THEN start the webpack-dev-server. Since the changes i made where update in the browser i just asumed that the changes where also updated (by Webpack-dev-server) in the build files. Since webpack-dev-server serves all the changes from memory and NOT to the build files i just have to remember to run the build command when i am done with the changes.

Comment: Yes. :) you have to run the build command before deploying. :)